# Kotlin and Java PECS

Tags: generics, kotlin, pecs

So my goal is use in Kotlin similar construction to Java PECS:

```
List<? extends MyMarkerInterface> => MutableList<out MyMarkerInterface>
```

When Jackson set after compiling data to this variable(list) it's ok. When I try to add item from Kotlin code , Kotlin says that I can add only Nothing (type) items.

So how do I put inside List child of MyMarkerInterface in Kotlin?

Comment: A Kotlin `List` is read only, so you can not add elements to it. You can however create a new list with the added element like this: `val newList = oldList + newElement`.

Comment: ok I improve my question 'cause I trying to simplify code. I have mutableList

Comment: PECS itself tells you that `? extends T` applies to the producer of `T`. What exactly is surprising about the fact you can't use it as the consumer?

Comment: Yeah, but before I will use it as producer, I need to collect my objects that I control to add to this producer

Answer (score 1):

This is about [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

(Because Kotlin distinguishes between mutable and immutable lists, it's stricter about this than Java, so you can't always compare directly.)

Suppose you have reference to a `MutableList<out MyMarkerInterface>`.  That parameter is the equivalent of Java's `<? extends MyMarkerInterface>`, and means you have a mutable list of `MyMarkerInterface` *or some subtype*.  But you don't know *which* subtype; it could be any type that implements your interface.

It could be a mutable list of `MyImplementingClassA`; so you clearly can't add an instance of `MyImplementingClassB` without risking violating its type-safety.  Nor vice versa.  In fact, without knowing any more about its type, **it's not safe to add *anything* to it**.  That's why Kotlin won't let you.  (The way it does that is by inferring the type [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), which is the ‘bottom’ type and has no values.)

However, if you want to get a value *out* of the list, you know it's some subtype of `MyMarkerInterface`, so you can happily treat it as a `MyMarkerInterface` reference.

That's why **`out` variance means the list is a *producer***: it can produce values for you safely, but it can't consume values because no type would be safe.

And it's the exact opposite for `in` variance, which is the equivalent of Java's `? super`.

(Which is of course the gist of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).  That exact phrasing only applies to Java — the Kotlin equivalent is ‘Producer Out, Consumer In’, which is probably too obvious to need an acronym! — but the principle's the same.)

**The only safe way to be a both producer *and* a consumer is to be *invariant***: plain old `MutableList<MyMarkerInterface>`.  That way, you know that you can get `MyMarkerInterface` values out *and* put `MyMarkerInterface` values in.

Things are different for `List`s, which are immutable in Kotlin.  (Or rather, you can't mutate them *through that reference*; you may be able to some other way.)  Because that reference won't let you put values in, **a `List` is not acting as a consumer, only a producer, and so `out` variance is fine for it**.

–

Your question doesn't give any detail, but you mentioned initialisation.  It's probably most common to create a `List` with all the values it will have up-front — either by calling [`listOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) or a constructor, or as the result of a [`map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) or similar operation.

However, you could also create some type of `MutableList`, set it up as needed, and then upcast it to `List` (which is a superinterface of `MutableList`), e.g.:

```
val ml = ArrayList<MyImplementingClassA>()
// …some computation which calls ml.add()…
val l = ml as List<out MyMarkerInterface>
```

…though in practice, you generally wouldn't need that last line; Kotlin [knows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) that `List`s have `out` variance, and so it'd upcast `ml` to `List<out MyMarkerInterface>` automatically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove out at all, and it works fine but without "? extends" when decompile code from bytecode after Kotlin